# More efficient way of searching window.location.href for a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a more efficient way of searching the window.location.href?

window.location.href: `http://www.example.com/6CATA/folder/file.html`

The current code I have is:

```
var searchWinHref = window.location.href;
if(searchWinHref.indexOf("/6CATA/") > -1) {
  alert('6CATA is in the window.location.href');
}
```

Which works just fine, but I'm trying to learn ways to optimise code where possible and if I need to do this a couple of times on a page, I'm curious to know if there's a more efficient way to do it?

EDIT:

To clarify, I need to occasionally search the URL for different variations, e.g: 6CATA & 6CATB etc.

Comment: premature optimization is the root of all evil... still: location.pathname might be .00000001 ms faster

Comment: That's probably the best way to do it, though you shouldn't have to do it multiple times.

Comment: If you need to do it more than once then store the result in a variable and check that...  `var index = searchWinHref.indexOf("/6CATA/");`

Comment: why not get the querystring, split it on '&' and store the results in an array as a variable? that way the lookup is done once and you have everything that has been passed in stored in a nice fast variable for future reference.

Comment: @jammypeach - This has nothing to do with the querystring.  He's checking the URL.

Comment: @Archer so he is. sorry, brain on strike today.

Comment: @jammypeach We all have those days! :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsperf.com/test-vs-match-vs-indexof-vs-search-2/2

Here is a benchmark, no need for optimization in this case

Comment: Although several answers have been really helpful - thanks Pieter for including an informative benchmark! :)

Answer (score 2):

No, that's quite fine. You might use `location.pathname.split('/').contains("6CDATA")`, but this is quite equivalent. If you want to optimise your code and really care about such micro-optimisation, cache the result in a variable if you need it a couple of times.

Comment: [Contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) is Fx17+ only

Comment: @mplungjan: I did expect a prototype.js-like `contains` on arrays, but yes - just hate writing `!=-1` :-)

Comment: >-1 or >=0 is more to your liking? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `window.location.pathname`, but you are not going to get any speed boost from that small chunk of code.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance this looks fine - especially if you are only calling it a couple of times.

Are you sure you need to do this checking client-side, though? This might be something that is better suited to do on the server. But that is up to you...

Comment: we only have access to client side - it's a closed CMS system unfortunately!

Comment: Ah... well in that case, there you go :)